# iOS Auto Layout When Loading Another Nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a detail view in a story board.  I want to load another Nib in that view when a certain condition is met.  But when I do, the auto layout its all screwed you.

I am trying to display the UIView above the UIWebView like an overlay view.  I want the UIView to have the same ratio of the device with a maximum height of 400 between the top and bottom layout guide.

Here is the code I used to load the Nib:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UINib *s = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"Square1" bundle:nil];
    NSArray *array = [s instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    StopView *stopView = (StopView *)[array objectAtIndex:0];

    [stopView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:stopView];

    id topGuide = self.topLayoutGuide;
    id bottomGuide = self.bottomLayoutGuide;
    UIWebView *webView = self.detailWebView;

    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(stopView, topGuide, bottomGuide, webView);

    // this is here to stop the auto layout from reporting that the guides has
    // ambiguous layout
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[topGuide]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[bottomGuide]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];


    // center the stop view in the super view, both lines below are needed
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-(>=12)-[stopView(<=400)]-(>=12)-|"
                                                                      options: 0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:views]];

    // set the height to a ratio of the width
    NSLayoutConstraint *con2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:stopView
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                            relatedBy:0 toItem:stopView
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                           multiplier:0.66667f constant:0];
    [self.view addConstraint:con2];

    // center the Stop View X,Y with the super view
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:stopView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1.0f constant:0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:stopView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                         multiplier:1.0f constant:0]];

    NSLog(@"Calling configureView from viewDidLoad");
    [self configureView];
}
```

Here are some screen shots:

[image: Story Board Detail View][image: Nib in Xcode][image: View when running]

As you can see in the third screen shot, my background is not showing. And you can see the **T** from the UILabel that placed at the top in design mode.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do. A size of <=400 is not enough to define the width of your view. A width of 0 would fulfill that constraint and your two edge constraints. You also don't have anything to define the height, so since 0 can satisfy your width constraint, the height can also be 0. You need to say what outcome you want when you add the stopView.

Comment: I used VisualLayout to set the height to no more than 400 points and created constraints set width.

Comment: Do you have other constraints on the width that you're not showing?

Comment: No I don't.  The only one I have in the code is the one that sets the ratio.  Do you believe I need some?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my first comment. A size of <=400 can be anything from 0 to 400. Your two edge constraints mean that it can't be wider than 320 -12 - 12 = 296. So, those constraints together mean that the view can be between 0 and 296 points wide, and it looks like the system is choosing 0. What width do you actually want? Why are you using >= constraints?

Comment: With my formatting string missing the orientation, I believe it defaults to vertical.  12 points is minimum gap I would like between the top and bottom guide.  Also with a maximum height of 400 points and width with a ratio 2/3 of the height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61286/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-black-frog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a vertical constraint, you need to put a "V:" in front of the string. To get a view to be 400 max, but be as big as it can given the top and bottom spacing constraints for a smaller screen, you need to use the priority of the constraint,

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(>=12)-[stopView(==400@900)]-(>=12)-|"
                                                                  options: 0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:views]];
```

The system will try to make the height of stopView as close to 400 as possible while maintaining a spacing of at least 12 to the top and bottom.